# Application Request Routing as Reverse Proxy - Error 500.19 for Absolute URI

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy

I've installed "IIS Application Request Routing (ARR) 2.5" and "IIS URL Rewrite 2.0" on IIS 7.5 in order to create reverse proxy/cache for program listening on localhost.

Problem: URL rewrite doesn't work for absolute URI, it works only for relative URL. According to documentation [1], this is expected behaviour, but example [2] shows that rewrite should work also for absolute URI if proxy is enabled. Unfortunately, the error (500.19 / 0x80070002) is the same even if proxy is enabled. Is there some IIS setting I have to modify? I use default installation provided by hosteurope.de.

Here is web.config snippet:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="test_FAIL" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^test1/(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://google.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="test_OK" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^test2/(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

[1] - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rewrite_action

[2] - http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 500.19 / 0x80070002 was caused by non-existent cache directory. One must also create the cache directory, it's not sufficient to specify the path!